# Ag-grid not working with angular and webpack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack, ag-grid

I am trying to get ag-grid to work with webpack.
I've done the standard thing by adding ag-grid through npm and added the reference to webpack.config by doing this:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {"ag-grid" : path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.js")
}
```

The file gets resolved and loaded into the index file just fine. And I've done the following for angular.

```
angular.module("cs-app", [require("ag-grid").name]);
```

Webpack also resolves this file and gets included and loaded up but when I run the app I get the following error.

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularGridGlobalFunction due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'angularGridGlobalFunction' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I can't find the name angularGridGlobalFunction in ag-grid.js but when I comment out the reference to ag-grid then the app works just fine.

So anyone suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so ag-grid does not need aliasing in the webpack.config.js so I removed that and aliased the node_modules folder.

```
resolve     : {
    alias         : {
        // bind version of jquery-ui
        "jquery-ui" : "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js",      
        // bind to modules;
        modules     : path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        components  : path.join(__dirname, "components"),
        libs        : path.join(__dirname, "bower_components"),
    }
},
```

I add at the top of my module file

```
require("ag-grid");
require("modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.css");
require("modules/ag-grid/dist/theme-fresh.css");
```

And changed the angular module reference

```
angular.module("cs-app", ["agGrid"]);
```

And whatta you know it worked

If you like it hit me with an upvote! Thanks

Comment: isn't the name of the angular module 'agGrid'? In any case, still no luck for me...

Comment: Yeah true agGrid you are right, this setup works fine for me, you must be doing something else wrong then, have you aliased the node_modules folders in webpack.config? I added some more code this is the exact working setup for me.

Comment: Yes, Thanks solved it after  debugging, added answer. I guess there is a 50% chance  it works without a shim.

Comment: With this method, you still need the line : agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular); for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me, first the solution:

```
npm install imports-loader --save-dev
```

Then in my code, add this to the loaders array in the webpack-config.js

```
{ test: require.resolve("ag-grid"), loader: "imports?importedAngular=angular" },
```

then the problem:

The ag-grid in npm in npm is not "npm ready", there is no indication in the code that ag-grid requires("angular"). So webpack is free to put it anywhere in the file, and load it any time. In my case, when ag-grid loaded, angular and window.angular were undefined, so ag-grid loaded before angular. The ag-grid checks that  window.angular is defined before it creates the module, so the module is never created.

The steps above add a shim, to always load angular before ag-grid.

Comment: I assumed that you var app = require("angular"); before you did the require of ag-grid which is how it usually works... (you need to put the angular script tag before the agGrid tag) so if you had done that instead if your way which is a bit.. how to put it kindly.. a bit of mess, it would have worked... so it goes to show that assumption is the mother of all f***kups :) btw agGrid does not need to be ready webpack handles none commonjs files just fine

Comment: You are right about assumptions, because this is what I had and it did not work:
require('angular');
require('angular-ui-router');
require('angular-formly');
require('angular-toastr');
require('ag-grid');
I am not sure how you can assume what I had in my code...